# How do I get my method to return a specific value if the wrong type is entered as a parameter?

Tags: java

I'm on the final part of this particular problem. The method below returns the angle of between the hour hand and the minute hand of an analog clock (measured anticlockwise from the hour hand to the minute hand). It works fine but can't get it to work with arbitrary inputs (incorrect parameters specifically).

For example; if I were to put 27.227272727 in the seconds column (the wrong type) I would want it to return zero.

```
mport java.lang.Math;
/*
@author Joseph Adamson
*/
public class W1_E3_b{
     /**
       * @param hours
       * @param minutes
       * @param seconds
       * @return int value representing degrees
       */
    public static int timeToAngle(int hours, int minutes, int seconds){
       int hour = hours % 12;
       int minute = minutes % 60;
       int second = seconds % 60;

       double hAngle = 0.5 * (60 * hour + minutes);
       double mAngle = 0.1 * (6 * minute + second);
       double value = (hAngle - mAngle);
       int angle = (int)value;
       return 360 - Math.abs(Math.min(angle, 360 - angle));
    }
public static void main(String[]args){
    System.out.println(timeToAngle(13, 05, 27.272727272727));
  }
}
```

If I tried that particular input now I get the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method timeToAngle(int, int, int) in the type W1_E3_b is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, double)

    at W1_E3_b.main(W1_E3_b.java:24)
```

How do I get it to return 0 if it gets the wrong type WITHOUT using conditionals or loops?

Comment: Your exception is due to the fact, that your are giving a double to a method which is expecting an int. Normally the compiler should give you an error, so your programm won't compile. To check if your input is valid, you should use an if-statement

Comment: _can't get it to work with arbitrary inputs_ How will these arbitrary inputs be supplied?

Comment: _How do I get it to return 0 if it gets the wrong type WITHOUT using conditionals or loops?_ You want each supplied value to be an `int`, correct? So are you asking how to determine that the supplied value is an `int`?

Comment: Yes, without a conditional if possible.  Like in the example above, if it does get a double as a parameter, I want it to flag this and return 0.

Answer (score 1):

> WITHOUT using conditionals or loops

Change the *parameters* to **Strings** and surround in a `try` `catch` if an error occurs while parsing the string to an Integer it will `return 0`. The program won't run with the incorrect hardcoded input in the parameters.

```
public static int timeToAngle(String hours, String minutes, String seconds){
        try {
            int hour = Integer.parseInt(hours) % 12;
            int minute = Integer.parseInt(minutes) % 60;
            int second = Integer.parseInt(seconds) % 60;

        double hAngle = 0.5 * (60 * hour + Integer.parseInt(minutes));
        double mAngle = 0.1 * (6 * minute + second);
        double value = (hAngle - mAngle);
        int angle = (int) value;
        return 360 - Math.abs(Math.min(angle, 360 - angle));
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

> not allowed to change the parameters

When taking in an input surround those in a `try` `catch` when assigning the values to the parameters.

Example:

```
 try {
        //int hour = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        //int min = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        //int seconds = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        int hour = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        int min = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        int seconds = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        int angle = W1_E3_b.timeToAngle(hour, min, seconds);
        System.out.println(angle);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        int angle = 0;
        System.out.println(angle);
    }
```

Comment: this works perfectly. The only problem, which I failed to state before, is that I'm not allowed to change the parameters. They have to be int. Any other suggestions?

Comment: How will the inputs be given? @JAdamson

Answer (score 0):

With your prototype function is not possible le pass the double value.

For the good programming before you call your method you must use the if condition, her name is defensive programing.

Also, another solution is the use of the abstract class Number, your code can be rewritten with this code

```
public static int timeToAngle(Integer hours, Integer minutes, Number seconds){
       if(!(seconds instanceof Integer)){
           return 0;
       }
       Integer castSecond = (Integer)seconds;
       int hour = hours % 12;
       int minute = minutes % 60;
       int second = castSecond % 60;

       double hAngle = 0.5 * (60 * hour + minutes);
       double mAngle = 0.1 * (6 * minute + second);
       double value = (hAngle - mAngle);
       int angle = (int)value;
       return 360 - Math.abs(Math.min(angle, 360 - angle));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the compilation error you get when trying to pass in a double essentially *is* preventing misuse of your function. I suppose if you really wanted to you could make an overloaded version of the function that takes a double argument:

```
public static int timeToAngle(int hours, int minutes, double seconds){
    return 0;
}
```

But this is very confusing to read. And you have to make a version for every possible combination of int/double parameter types. Why not just rely on the compilation error to keep people from passing in doubles? Or if you want to support people passing in doubles, why not just change all the parameters to doubles and implement your function to do the math for fractional time values?

[EDIT]

It sounds like this is a homework problem, so I guess this is more about what the professor is looking for...